# Chrome Extension: audible property from tabs query return true even after the player (sound source) has been stopped

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do a tab query like, `chrome.tabs.query({ url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch*' })`. The resulting tabs object has a property named `audible` indicating whether the tab has audible sources playing. But even after pausing the youtube player, this property is coming as `true` for few seconds (maybe milliseconds). Is this the intentional one? In [this recording linked](https://vimeo.com/277805215), the audible prop will be returned as `true` for about 8 tries after actually passing the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/Wd4yXPAGE_U/L4CoKqAYBQAJ), this behavior is intentional and the audible property will be true even after the sound source is muted/paused for **2 seconds**.